# Uso de “gente”, “povo” e “pessoal”

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Habitualmente eu não tenho grandes dúvidas sobre quando é que devo utilizar uma das palavras “gente”, “povo” ou “pessoal”. Eu sou muito de usar “a gente” com o significado de “nós” mas aí não tem jeito de errar. Minha pergunta tem a ver com as conotações políticas e sociais.

No espanhol da Argentina existe o costume de diferenciar políticamente entre *pueblo* e *gente*. O primeiro soa mais formal, mais tradicional e também mais relacionado ao discurso conservador ou, alternativamente, ao discurso da esquerda política. O segundo é mais descontraído e tem ficado associado ao discurso liberal ou populista moderno, que tenta se aproximar às pessoas como indivíduos. Eu queria saber se “povo” e “gente” têm conotações parecidas na política lusoparlante.

Eu tenho ouvido falar em português de “o povo” com o significado de “as pessoas simples”, “as massas”, quase com o sentido de “a plebe”. É isso aceitável no discurso público?

Finalmente, já que “a gente” não pode ser usado com o significado de “as pessoas” (como em espanhol *la gente*), como é que o conjunto das pessoas é chamado? Eu tenho essa dúvida porque tenho a sensação de que “pessoal” só pode ser usado informalmente e só para se referir a um grupo de pessoas presentes (física ou figurativamente) perto do falante. Estou errado?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos começar com o uso de cada uma das palavras em frases.

**"gente"**

- **"A gente** não sabe por onde começar." (nós)
- **"Aquela gente** não presta." (aquelas pessoas)
- "É **gente que não sabe** o que quer." (são pessoas)
- "Isso aí **dá em gente**, não em bicho." (seres humanos)
- "Tu não és **gente**!" (tu não és um ser humano, és um animal)
- "**Minha gente** está passando fome." (minha família, meu povo, depende do contexto)
- "**Brava gente**, brasileira! Longe vá temor servil.
  Ou ficar a Pátria livre, ou morrer pelo Brasil." (bravo povo) p/ Dom Pedro I do Brasil (Dom Pedro IV de Portugal)
- "São todos **gente de bem**." (pessoas amigas e/ou do bem)
- "**Olha, gente**, vamos ser práticos e ...." (meus amigos, pessoal, aqueles que me ouvem)

**"povo"**

- "O **povo** das províncias do norte é bem hospitaleiro." (os habitantes)
- "O **povo** não tem pão". (a população. Neste caso, provavelmente as camadas mais carentes)
- "O **povo** vai às urnas amanhã". (todos os habitantes aptos a votar)
- "**O povo brasileiro**" (os habitantes do Brasil)
- "**O povo** quis linchar o bandido" (o grupo de pessoas presentes naquele local)

**pessoal**

- "O **pessoal** está a fim de ir ao jogo amanhã." (um grupo específico de pessoas e o meu interlocutor sabe de quem se trata)
- "**Ei, pessoal!**  Vocês não acham que já chega?"  (vocês que me ouvem)

Agora os comentários:
Quando eu falo **"o nosso povo"**, eu me refiro ao povo brasileiro em geral. Há pouco tempo, no entanto, um amigo discutiu comigo a respeito, alegando que **"o povo"** exclui aqueles que fazem parte da elite socioeconômica e tem mais o significado de **"as massas"** conforme citado pelo OP. Tentei encontrar alguma fonte para confirmar uma ou outra asserção, mas não encontrei.

**"Pessoal"** refere-se a um grupo de pessoas com quem falamos, e nesse caso é um vocativo, (e.g. **"Ei, pessoal, vamos embora."**) e também pode se referir àqueles de quem falamos ("**o pessoal** resolveu ir embora).  Da mesma forma que **"gente"**, **"pessoal" também pede o verbo na terceira pessoa do singular.**

**"A gente"** geralmente significa "nós", mas também pode significar **"as pessoas"** ("Estou me referindo à gente do interior que não sabe se expressar" , Isoladamente, **gente** significa **pessoas.** Vide os exemplos acima.

Comment: Por aqui no estado de São Paulo, "o povo" é o mesmo que "as pessoas". Se quiser excluir a elite, é dito "o povão". Isso informalmente.

Comment: @BrunoLopes  É assim que eu entendo, mas no RJ há quem ache que o povo = o povão.